# (Ruby on Rails) Displaying Posts Into Groups of 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the following code to display posts to my users.

_feed.html.erb partial:

```
<% @posts_by_month.each do |monthname, posts| %>
<%= monthname %>
<ul>
   <% posts.each do |post| %>
     <li><%= post.created_at %></li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
  def home
    if logged_in?
      @post  = current_user.posts.build
      @posts_by_month = current_user.feed.group_by { |post| post.created_at.strftime("%B") }
```

This renders my posts as follows:

```
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
Post 4
```

I want to change it so that the posts are displayed like:

```
Post 1         Post 2       Post 3
Post 4         etc          etc
etc
```

I've tried several approaches to this, including the in_groups_of(3) method however the way it is currently setup means nothing works. I feel like there is an obvious solution I'm missing - can anyone help?

[**Edit to expand on the in_groups_of(3) error**]

If I change line 4 in the _feed partial to:

```
<% posts.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |post| %>
```

It gives the error: undefined method `created_at' for #< Array:0xbb8f258 >

Answer (score 2):

The `#in_groups_of` method returns an Array of Arrays each containing 3 Post objects.
So you now also need to iterate over the returned array that contains your three Posts, something like:

```
<% posts.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |post_group| %>
   <% post_group.each do |post| %>
     <li><%= post.created_at %></li>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The logic makes sense however when I insert the above code into my feed partial each post is still displayed on its own line, rather than 3 per line as I want it to. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: This is happening because you are using <ul> and <li> tags which by default will always go vertically, to solve that will involve you needing to modify your html / css.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any suggestions as to how to modify the html /css to get the behaviour I want? Or an alternative to using <ul> and <li> tags?

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at using flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ that is a link to some flexbox basic, a lot of modern CSS frameworks use this for their column classes etc. so it is a good way to go I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [facets](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets) gem. This provides and `each_by` method. You can use `each_by` to create groups and iterate further on these groups.

Here is code snippet on how to use `each_by`

```
<div class = "small-9 columns vertical-border-left">
    <%- @client.contact_details.each_by(3) do |contact_details| %>
      <div class="row">
        <%- contact_details.each do |contact| %>
            <div class="small-3 columns small">
              <div> <%= contact.contact_detail_type %> contact </div>
              <div> <%= contact.contact_email %> </div>
              <div> <%= contact.contact_phone %> </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %> 
</div>
```